# how to view xml data with bullet and special character

Tags: php, xml, special-characters

I need to display the following content which  is in xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<source>
<publisher>greenindustryjobs</publisher>
 <publisherurl>http://www.greenindustryjobs.com</publisherurl>
<job>
 <title>Tax Manager</title>
 <description><![CDATA[Manages day-to-day tax department functions including federal, state and local tax compliance, planning and research. Supervises, develops and evaluates staff to ensure effecient operation of tax department. Coordinates with foreign locations on international tax matters. 

Bachelor's degree in finance or accounting. CPA and 8-10 yrs. of tax experience with a "Big 4" CPA firm and a major corporation desired  •Direct all 
 •Provide ]]></description>
 <referencenumber>1</referencenumber>
 <date>2006-04-13</date>
 </job>
</source>
```

I used all the following methods but no luck.

method 1:

```
//$content = utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://localhost/jobhills/test1.xml'));

//$content = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $content);
```

method 2:

```
$content = simplexml_load_string('test1.xml', null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

I need to view the following xml through the browser

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<source>
  <publisher>abc</publisher>
  <publisherurl>www.abc.com</publisherurl>
  <job>
    <title>Tax Manager</title>
    <description><![CDATA[Manages day-to-day tax department functions including federal, state and local tax compliance, planning and research. Supervises, develops and evaluates staff to ensure effecient operation of tax department. Coordinates with foreign locations on international tax matters. 

Bachelor's degree in finance or accounting. CPA and 8-10 yrs. of tax experience with a "Big 4" CPA firm and a major corporation desired]]></description>
    <referencenumber>1</referencenumber>
    <date>2006-04-13</date>
  </job>
  <job>
    <title>Accounting/Business Manager</title>
    <description><![CDATA[Duties and Responsibilities
քirect all day-to-day accounting and administrative operations for multiple offices in the Northern Virginia area. 
֐rovide hands on accounting support and supervision including financial reporting, accounts payable, billing, accounts receivable, payroll coordination, collections, financial statement preparation and analysis. 
քevelop, manage, and implement operational and administrative procedures and policies for the business including establishing and maintaining accounting procedures, fiscal reporting methods, procedures for payment of invoices, and other related activities.  
ցssist Project Management in executing project cost/schedule control responsibilities. 
֐repare and monitor the annual budget and advise management of budget status.  
֒esponsible for collection of past due accounts including client coordination and contact, maintenance of recording and control procedures involving the collection, evaluation, processing, preparation, submission and reconciliation of accounts. 
֐repares and approves billing documents and submits invoices for payment approval, reviews and approves all financial and accounting records and transactions. 
փooperate with internal/external audits and implement approved recommendations. 
ցdditional support services functions will include payroll coordination, human resources, employee benefit management, purchasing, communications, and marketing for multiple offices.   
ցssist in identifying accounting and administrative hardware and software requirements and support the implementation of new technology. 
ցttend business meetings to keep apprised of other operations and provide input to enhance the department's operation. 
քirect the work of other administrative employees including selection, hiring, evaluating performance, employee training/development, promoting and any disciplinary action.
Qualifications
ւachelor's degree in Accounting or in Business Administration with supplemental coursework in accounting.
ֆive (5) years of work experience in an accounting-related role required with accounts payable/receivable, budgeting, and office management experience, or an equivalent combination of work experience and education.  
֓uccessful experience in collection of accounts. 
ցbility and desire to work in a cooperative manner and to make management decisions.  
օxperience working with accounting software (Deltek preferred) and working knowledge of Cost Accounting Standards.]]></description>
    <referencenumber>5</referencenumber>
    <date>2008-07-10</date>
  </job>
</source>
```

Comment: working well here: https://eval.in/514783. might be a problem in HTML environment?

Comment: and What output you are getting ? did you try with utf8_decode??

Comment: I got error message "   This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document 
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

Comment: I also got error in live url